# Trying to have the first page of my React App show a navbar (using React bootstrap), but nothing showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a personal website as my first project using React, but for some reason my Component is not rendering on the first page. My terminal is saying everything is being built correctly and when I just put Hello World on my index.html it shows up, but when I try to render my NavigationBar it does not work. I'm sorry if this is a stupid fix, but I'm new to React so try to bear with me here! Here is the code

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar'
import './index.css'

class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <NavigationBar/>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
export default App
```

**NavigationBar.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'

    export default class NavigationBar extends React.Component{
      render(){
        return(
          <Container className = "nav">
            <Navbar bg = "dark" expand = "lg">
              <Navbar.Brand href = "#home">My name </Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls = "basic-navbar-nav"/>
              <Navbar.Collapse id = "basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className = "mr-auto">
                  <Nav.Link href = "Education">Education</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href = "Employment">Employment </Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href = "Projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href = "Leadership/Activites">Leadership</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href = "Languages">Languages</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href = "hobbies">Hobbies</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
          </Container>
        )
      }
    }
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Website</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id = 'app'></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to `import` the `React-Bootstrap` files (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets)

Comment: @JeffBerlin Hmmm. i just did what you said and imported 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; into my index.js file and put the CDN into my index.html file but still nothing is showing up.

Comment: Are you getting a warning for not having `import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'`?

Comment: @averagej63 Are you getting any error in the console. You have imported Navbar how about other components like Nav,Container etc

Comment: @JeffBerlin I don't have any warnings in my terminal, everything has a green 'built' next to it and the last line is 'compiled successfully'.  I see a lot of Nav items being built in my terminal, so I think everything is installed correctly... Here are my dependencies too if that helps

Comment: "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"

Comment: Hi, it looks like you need to import ```Container``` and ```Nav``` from ```react-bootstrap```

Comment: @rajeshkumar I see Nav, NavContext, NavItem, NavLink, AbstractNav, AbstractNavItem being built in the terminal

Comment: @rcoro That fixed it! Container was missing. Thank you so much